# Pivot point is binded to the 3D cursor, scale with G only works with Ctrl

Tags: transforms, 3d-cursor

I'm a moron, I know. This is my first real project in Blender I have a goal, and I'm walking through it step by step I'm fighting with Blender, my old crappy pc, I find out not just how to do it, but how to make it with a final render before the end of the epidemic.. and time to time, accidentally I push a combination of keys, and kill the whole software. Pls help, as google doesn't. Now:

- The pivo point of every object is the 3d cursor (when I rotate, for example) - nothing is locked on the 3D cursor part of view panel.
- Moving with G, only works if I push Ctrl when I'm moving my mouse, after G.

I just want to go back to normal, thanks..

Comment: I think we'd need to see an image of your Blender window to answer that one! In blender, from The Window menu, select Screenshot and save the image to your desktop. Then edit your above question and drag and drop the image into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pushed shift + tab (shortkey of the button with magnet icon) accidentally